# Merging .dat files using Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-lab

I'm attempting to merge two .dat files so I can scan through them both for a project. I have tried searching it up, and all I can find is how to merge csv files. How do I merge these two files using Pandas? If its necessary or is just plain easier to convert them, how do I do so? I am using Jupyterlabs, Python 3.8, and am quite new to both.

Comment: What's a .dat file?

Comment: show us your code, and your stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df_1 = pd.read_csv('file_1.dat', sep='\s\s+', engine='python') 
df_2 = pd.read_csv('file_2.dat', sep='\s\s+', engine='python')

df_3 = df_1.merge(df2, on = "common_column")
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but like the other suggestion it tells me that my first file does not exist. Because both suggestions have yielded the same result, there is probably something extremely simple that I am missing.

Comment: make sure you have the right path ("file_1.dat" is not the same as ../file_1.dat), please give more details about your tree directory.

Comment: New to python, unsure of what you mean.

Comment: In order to call a file this way "file_1.dat" make sure they are in the same directory as your script(code), example:  /your_project/your_script.py -- /your_project/file_1.dat

Answer (score 1):

Merging should go pretty much the same as csv:

```
import pandas as pd


df1 = pd.read_csv("fileA.dat")
df2 = pd.read_csv("fileB.dat")

df = pd.concat([df1, df2])

df.to_csv('df.dat')
```

this does however, partly depend on the conventions used in the dat file. You might have to use a different parser to go through the files